# how to open a specific folder with gallery or file manager that contains images and videos

Tags: android

A folder contains only images and videos,
When I click on a button with OnClickListener(), then I want to open that folder with gallery or file manager, and show images and videos that are saved in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for that event, that will fetch the following code (this is for images):

```
path = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />;
}
```

or you can use this PLUGIN https://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo